# How did Euclid arrive at the law of reflection $r=i$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, optics

The law of reflection, $r=i$, is attributed to Euclid. In his [Optics](http://philomatica.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Optics-of-Euclid.pdf) text he refers to it, at the end of Page 360 in relation to Graph 19, and says he has demonstrated it in his [Catoptrics](https://web.calstatela.edu/faculty/hmendel/Ancient%20Mathematics/Euclid/Catoptrics/Catoptrics%201/EuclidCatoptrics.1.html). But I do not understand his reasoning in Catoptrics. (To make the matter more confusing, some historians claim Catoptrics was written by another person several hundred years after Euclid. Or that there were more than one Catoptrics.)

Did he think since he can look at an image in a flat mirror without distortion then $r=i$? Is it based on a geometrical reasoning or on experiments.

Did Euclid have a concept of ``shortest distance'' for the light path? [Some websites](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/316/lectures/node125.html) claim this but I have not seen it in the translation of Optics, or in well-referenced papers. Did anyone before Fermat thought of shortest time or distance in relation to light path?

Comment: The idea of shortest path in the law of reflection goes back to [Hero's Catoptrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle#Fermat_vs._the_Cartesians), not pseudo-Euclid's. However, as it is more complex than the equality of angles, it can hardly be used to "arrive" at it. It was an empirical surmise that lended itself to a simple geometric formulation.